# Entity Framework model updates, but model's list of other items not updating

Tags: entity-framework-5

Here's my issue. I revived an old text based game of mine that used flat files for saving and loading. I have been porting my old C++ code to C# using MVC 4 with Entity Framework 5 and SQL Server 2012. Rendering pages with Razor views are straightforward. The problem comes when building a wizard for creating/editing my rooms.

A Room contains a collection of Exit objects. All works fine when I first create the room and assign exits. What does not work is when I edit the room and change the exits. Putting a breakpoint in my edit code shows the exit value has changed, no problem setting the room state to modified, and the room appears to save just fine i.e. changes to name and description get updated. However, the exit info does not.

I tried to loop through the list of exits, mark each exit as modified, but that throws all sorts of errors during save. My question is this. What is the correct way to update the list of exits on my room model?

I've tried other solutions here, refresh, copying new values to old values before saving, but nothing works. How do I get the exit objects to update to my database. Thanks in advance.

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

}

public class Room : Entity
{
    public virtual ICollection<Exit> Exits { get; set; }
}

public class Exit : Entity
{
    // The room to which we belong
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }

    // The room to which we connect
    public int? ToRoomId { get; set; }
    public Room ToRoom { get; set; }
}
```

My repository methods

```
public IEnumerable<Room> AllRoomsInclusive()
{
    var rooms = Context.Rooms.Include(r => r.Exits).ToList();
    return rooms;
}

public void Update(Room room)
{
    Context.Entry(room).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

public void Save()
{
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I see that ToRoomId is updated in controller's edit method i.e. was ToRoomId 6 during get method and edit during post method set it as ToRoomId 10. This value is not reflected in the database on save.

Comment: Do you seriously believe anyone can answer your question without you supplying code that illustrates what you're doing?

Comment: So, Mystere Man and I get in a tiff and my question is on hold. I've updated as requested and now ask forgiveness from Mystere Man. What else is unclear about my question such that I can move forward?

Comment: Now you're providing some information to help narrow down the problem, it was impossible to do so before, which was why multiple people agreed it was unclear.  Perhaps multiple people will now find it has enough information to at least start.  I am not sure it has quite enough yet.  For example, where is your Context defined, and how are you instantiating it?  What is your Context defined as?  Have you validated that the Room object bound in your Update method contains all the correct information?

Comment: Yes. Inspecting the Room object that comes through my post method I can see that the Room object has the correct id and the name and description fields have new values. These update fine in the database.

The list of exit objects has one exit for testing purposes. The exit  Id and RoomId are correct. I also see that the ToRoomId has the updated value.

The Context is defined in a repository. The Context is a class that implements DbContext where I simply declare my DbSets.

Comment: Are you inserting a new room id?  If so, you need to make the state Added, not Modified.  If you're changing the Roomid, then you need to also delete the previous room id.

Comment: From the create screen I perform an add and the Room with the new exit object works just fine. I redirect to my index method, retrieve the list of rooms, and show a standard list of rooms index page with an edit link. Through my get method, I take the id, retrieve the room object and include any exit objects and show the edit page. I make changes and call the post method for my edit page. Room name and description show changes. The exit in the room is not updated. Checking the database shows that the ToRoomId was not updated. I am not changing the Room Id.

Comment: Clarification -- The ToRoomId value for the exit in the room shows the change I made on my edit page. After calling update and save, this value is not updated to my database. The exit Id is not changed on the edit page and is present on the exit object in the room. I do this via @Html.HiddenFor(...)

Comment: Yes, but you're only setting the Room to modified.  You're not setting the Exit to modified.

Comment: See my original post. I tried looping through the exits and marking them as modified. Back to the original question. Is this the correct way to mark the exits as modified or should I be doing something else?

Comment: You neglected to mention what "throws all sorts of errors" means.

Comment: Software is a very precise thing.  Computers do exactly what you tell them to do, not what you meant for them to do.  Telling us what you meant for them to do doesn't help us solve the problems of what you told it to do, unless you also tell us what you told it to do.

Comment: The monkey just did something vulgar with the football. Uncommented my  loop to get the exact error and the damn thing worked. No clue why it failed before. I've made no changes to the code or to the database.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with throwing things at the wall, is you end up dismissing the correct path because of some unrelated problem.

Comment: Will mark as answered the moment this comes off hold.

Comment: It probably won't.. so don't worry about it.  Corrected the downvote for you at least.